# How to subset a multidimensional contingency table with values of a vector (i.e. each value specifies a dimension)?

Tags: r, arrays, subset, contingency

I have a multidimensional contingency table of 4 variables. And I need to get the values out of that table, using a length-4 vector. The whole reason for doing this is to be able to get a huge list of such vectors and find a corresponding output from the contingency table.
Is there a good way to convert `c(1,2,3,4)` into `my.table[1,2,3,4]`?
Here's an example of what I'm currently doing with only one vector as an input:

```
v = c(1,2,3,4)
my.table = table(my.data.frame[,c("x","y","z","w")])
eval(str2lang(paste0("my.table[", paste0(v, collapse = ", "), "]")))
```

And this is what I'm doing with a big list of input vectors, which is in my case a data frame:

```
data.frame.of.inputs = data.frame(x = sample(1:4, 100, T), y = sample(1:4, 100, T), 
                                  z = sample(1:4, 100, T), w = sample(1:4, 100, T))
my.table = table(some.other.data.frame[,c("x","y","z","w")])
apply(data.frame.of.inputs,1,function(rw) 
eval(str2lang(paste0("my.table[", paste0(rw, collapse = ", "), "]"))))
```

Note: to make this code run you can initialize `my.data.frame` and `some.other.data.frame` with the same statement:

```
data.frame(x = sample(1:4, 100, T), y = sample(1:4, 100, T), 
           z = sample(1:4, 100, T), w = sample(1:4, 100, T))
```

I don't like my current solution not just because it is ugly, but also because it seems to be a very long way of doing something simple.

Also, as a side-quest of mine: is there a way to subset a table via attributes(my.table)$variable.name?

Comment: I'm not clear on the meaning of your "side quest":  can you give an example (remembering that you can do indirect addressing via `attributes(my.table)[[var]]` where `var` is a character vector of length 1 ...) ?

Comment: @BenBolker I meant that i want to find a way to get values of my.table where x == such and such, y == so and so, z == such and such and so on. I understand that I can rely on the order of dimensions of the table, but it would make code a bit more elegant if I could skip saving the correct order, and just ask the table for values in given dimension names. I tried my.table[v], with no luck, it is an array after all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `?"["`:

> When indexing arrays by ‘[’ a single argument ‘i’ can be a
> matrix with as many columns as there are dimensions of ‘x’;
> the result is then a vector with elements corresponding to
> the sets of indices in each row of ‘i’.

With one vector:

```r
my.table[rbind(v)]
```

(i.e., convert the vector into a one-row matrix)

Multiple inputs:

```r
my.table[as.matrix(data.frame.of.inputs)]
```

Comment: wow thank you so much! didn't know that! The first question that springs to mind instantly is how to get a vector out, not a value. I mean, with the ugly method it is possible to select my.table[ , 2, 3, 4] - so it must be possible with this method too, or so I thought. in the help section it is specified that I can put a zero in a matrix to "ignore" a corresponding column, but I don't really get the meaning of "ignore". i tried my.table[matrix(c(0,2,3,4),1)] and got integer(0) as an output, which is "wrong" - as the table contains values for those levels

Comment: @iliyamalecki having a vector 2,3,4 is not valid since you do not know whether you need `my.table[,2,3,4]` or `my.table[2,,3,4]` or `my.table[2,3,,4]` do you see whhere I am going with this? So if you have a vector, you need to specify all the dimensions.

Comment: @Onyambu I understand the reasons, but I don't understand the workarounds. Why doesn't matrix with 0,2,2,1 work as expected?

Comment: @iliyamalecki there is no subsetting of 0. eg. `x<- 1:4; x[0]`  why would you say *as expected?* No its not expected

Comment: @Onyambu oops I didn't read the docs too well, it turns out in case of indexing by matrix, 0 will result in ommiting that matrix row entirely, not a target's column. Yet, x[matrix(c(0,2)] is valid and will yield 2 as an output